# Error :: Method not found: 'System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive

Tags: c#, c#-ziparchive

I am using .NET Framework 4.7 for development.

The application uses the below code to create zip files.

```
using (ZipArchive zipArch = ZipFile.Open(zipFileName, ZipArchiveMode.Create))
{
    foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(outputPath))
    {
        zipArch.CreateEntryFromFile(file, Path.GetFileName(file));
    }
}
```

When deployed on local server the process works correctly and a zip file is created but when deployed to another server the process fails with this error message..

> Error :: Method not found: 'System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive
> System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.Open(System.String,
> System.IO.Compression.ZipArchiveMode)'.

Comment: Did you check the .net framework version installed on your target server ?

Comment: Yes I checked its 4.7

Comment: Could you upgrade to 4.7.2 + and test it again ?

Comment: Can you please let me know the reason behind updating to 4.7.2 framework

Comment: There is a related bug before 4.7.2  https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/pull/2362

Comment: thanks will try that